# Problems in password_verify() and password_hash(BCRYPT)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, password-encryption, php-password-hash

So I was making a login system with MySQL and PHP and found out about the password_hash() and password_verify() functions. Then, just for satisfaction, I tried it on [paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/B6BT9iT7Ueuz8TZA9tI2-A)
and it worked fine. Then, I created a hash on my website (of "1234" and echoed it, then inserted it by myself into a MySQL database for even more satisfaction. And later on, I got it using mysqli_fetch_array and did the following:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT UN, PWD FROM chat WHERE UN = 'test2'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row["PWD"]."<br>";
    // echoes the hash I copied and inserted into MySQL.
    if (password_verify("1234", $row["PWD"])) {
        echo "Verified!";
    } else {
        echo "Not verified!";
    }
}
```

and whatever I do it says "Not verified!"

 then I try this:

```
    if (password_verify("1234", password_hash("1234", PASSWORD_BCRYPT)) {
        echo "Verified!";
    } else {
        echo "Not verified!";
    }
```

and it says "Verified!"

 So what should I do?
EDIT:
The insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO unpw VALUES "$2y$10$ilT3uKq.9AbVuVIqJJFaK.wFyuzZCfmZ5Swjy9mUMEgSn896VNEvO";
```

Table structure:

```
Field Type     Null Key Default Extra
ID    int(11)  NO   PRI         auto_increment
UN    tinytext NO   
PWD   text     NO   
By DESCRIBE unpw
```

P.S. I inserted using the Adminer UI not SQL command but this is the command and there is no problem in MySQL it's in password_verify(); I just tried this (still errors):

```
$hash = the hash;
echo password_verify("1234", $hash);
```

doesn't echo 1

Comment: Please add the part where you set/insert the password to the database, and the table description of your chat-table (e.g. `show create table chat`).

Comment: Also share what size the `PWD` column is set to in the database.

Comment: Btw, `if (password_verify("1234", $row["PWD"]) {` should throw a syntax error since you're only closing the password_verify() function, but not the if-statement. You're missing the closing `)`

Comment: The column in the database must be at least 60 characters long

Comment: Well it is `text` and it echoes a correct hash the same I got but password_verify doesn't

Comment: Set it to varchar.

Comment: You need to check what kind of hash you are getting from the database, something must not be right.

Comment: Why the linked example is using 12345 and here you are using 1234?

Comment: It seems that the hash you have supplied '$2y$10$ilT3uKq.9AbVuVIqJJFaK.wFyuzZCfmZ5Swjy9mUMEgSn896VNEvO' is not a hash for "1234". Also the link you have provided in piaza.io, is checking the password 12345 not 1234.

I suggest you to clean your database and start again. Maybe you misspelled something when saving your hash.